# .NET SQLConnection Idiom

Tags: .net, sqlconnection

Is instantiating a .NET SQLConnection object on a per request basis (e.g. in the IOC container), for use with all the queries to be performed during that request typical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is reasonably common: because of [*connection pooling*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), an optimization technique that lets your program implicitly reuse connections to the database, this does not have as adverse an impact on performance as one might think.